# Poof that $\binom{n}{0}+2\binom{n}{1}+2^2\binom{n}{2}+...+2^n\binom{n}{n}=x^n\text{ for every }n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics

I probably have to use Newton's binomial, but i can't interpret this expression well because i just started stydying Discrete Mathematics and am struggling with this question.

The objective is to proove that exists a x ∈ N

$\binom{n}{0}+2\binom{n}{1}+2^2\binom{n}{2}+...+2^n\binom{n}{n}=x^n\text{ for every }n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: How is that true for every $x\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: No one can provide you such a p**r**oof because $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^k$ does not equal $x^n$, it equals $3^n$, and that is a straightforward consequence of the binomial theorem.

Comment: @PedroQuintans Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

By [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

$$\binom{n}{0}+2\binom{n}{1}+2^2\binom{n}{2}+…+2^n\binom{n}{n}=(1+2)^n=3^n$$

Comment: You **can't** prove what you say you want to because the right side depends upon x while the left side is independent of x!

Comment: @user247327 Sorry, what I can't say?

Answer (score 1):

A possible expansion of $x^n$ using the binomial theorem for $a=1$ and $b=x-1$ is:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb N^* , \ \binom{n}{0}+(x-1)\binom{n}{1}+(x-1)^2\binom{n}{2}+…+(x-1)^n\binom{n}{n}=(1+x-1)^n=x^n$$

I tried to guess your question

Comment: there are infinitely many of such decomposition with $(a+b)^n$ such that $a+b=x$

Comment: You are right. I just chose a decomposition with a formula as similar as possible to the one he provided.

Comment: maybe you should highlight this point in your answer in order to do not give the idea that it is a special expansion

Comment: I did it. Thank you